# Tempusdominus Datetimepicker deformed or not showing as compared to Bootstrap examples

Tags: bootstrap-4, datetimepicker, timepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I would like my datetimepicker to be shown as the 5th datetimepicker in https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/#no-icon-input-field-only (No Icon (input field only)).

However, when using the CDNJS only, the output is a deformed version of what is shown in the examples. In an attempt to fix the problem, I included the source code found in the link below by attributing a local path. This makes the datetimepicker not showing up at all.

Source code: https://github.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4

Neither including the CDNJS only, the source code (local path) only nor both works.

I would like to be able to change the colours in the future so doing it with a source code would be more beneficial for me...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/datetimepicker/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/datetimepicker/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
```

```
 <div class="col-lg-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="datetimepicker5" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#datetimepicker5" placeholder="Data e Hora">
 </div>
<script>
        $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) to get the dropdown to work as intended, i had to add

- font-awesome.css
- moment.js
- tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js
- tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.css

(2) to style the calendar which opens up, i added the following: `.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td{ color:red;}` you can make relevant changes yourself

complete **working snippet** below;

```css
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.9.0/styles/github.min.css" />

<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/theme/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="datetimepicker5" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#datetimepicker5" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker();
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How could I inspect the dropdown menu? even when checking the forcing the element states it goes away so I can't see the styling of the dropdown menu...(I am on a Mac and using Chrome)

Comment: you're right... i just checked out `https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/theme/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.css` and got an idea of how the popup calendar is setup and designed